# How to receive an incoming mms and write into android database

Tags: android

I am trying to make my own messaging application.I am able to send sms and mms I am able to write incoming sms into android database. I have made my app default messaging app. But how to show incoming mms into my inbox with images and text. I am using  https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms as a library.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `MmsReceivedReceiver` class of that library. Take a look on it implementation:

```
public class MmsReceivedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MmsReceivedReceiver";

    public static final String MMS_RECEIVED = "com.klinker.android.messaging.MMS_RECEIVED";
    public static final String EXTRA_FILE_PATH = "file_path";
    public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION_URL = "location_url";

    private static final String LOCATION_SELECTION =
            Telephony.Mms.MESSAGE_TYPE + "=? AND " + Telephony.Mms.CONTENT_LOCATION + " =?";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "MMS has finished downloading, persisting it to the database");

        String path = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_FILE_PATH);
        Log.v(TAG, path);

        FileInputStream reader = null;
        try {
            File mDownloadFile = new File(path);
            final int nBytes = (int) mDownloadFile.length();
            reader = new FileInputStream(mDownloadFile);
            final byte[] response = new byte[nBytes];
            reader.read(response, 0, nBytes);

            DownloadRequest.persist(context, response,
                    new MmsConfig.Overridden(new MmsConfig(context), null),
                    intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_URL),
                    Utils.getDefaultSubscriptionId(), null);

            Log.v(TAG, "response saved successfully");
            Log.v(TAG, "response length: " + response.length);
            mDownloadFile.delete();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MMS received, file not found exception", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MMS received, io exception", e);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "MMS received, io exception", e);
                }
            }
        }

        handleHttpError(context, intent);
        DownloadManager.finishDownload(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_URL));
    }

    private void handleHttpError(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final int httpError = intent.getIntExtra(SmsManager.EXTRA_MMS_HTTP_STATUS, 0);
        if (httpError == 404 ||
                httpError == 400) {
            // Delete the corresponding NotificationInd
            SqliteWrapper.delete(context,
                    context.getContentResolver(),
                    Telephony.Mms.CONTENT_URI,
                    LOCATION_SELECTION,
                    new String[]{
                            Integer.toString(PduHeaders.MESSAGE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION_IND),
                            intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_URL)
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

and implement something like `SmsReceiver` from example of library.